# Jqgrid frozen columns - can't get them to freeze unless I manually resize the grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have read every post I can find on Frozen columns in jqgrid.  And have implemented the following code.
The result... when I go to my spreadsheet grid in my app the 3 cols are NOT frozen.  BUt if I drag the little resize icon in the lower left ever so slightly then POP they 3 columns are now frozen.

Why doesn't it work when the spreadsheet is first drawn?
Here's the code:

```
           var $grid = $("#list4");
            var resizeColumnHeader = function () {
                var rowHight, resizeSpanHeight,
                    // get the header row which contains
                    headerRow = $(this).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                        .find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr.ui-jqgrid-labels");

                // reset column height
                headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
                    this.style.height = '';
                });

                // increase the height of the resizing span
                resizeSpanHeight = 'height: ' + headerRow.height() + 'px !important; cursor: col-resize;';
                headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
                    this.style.cssText = resizeSpanHeight;
                });

                // set position of the dive with the column header text to the middle
                rowHight = headerRow.height();
                headerRow.find("div.ui-jqgrid-sortable").each(function () {
                    var $div = $(this);
                    $div.css('top', (rowHight - $div.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px');
                });
            };
        var fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs = function () {
                var $rows;
                if (this.grid === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                if (this.grid.fbDiv !== undefined) {
                    $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.bDiv);
                    $('>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.fbDiv).each(function (i) {
                        var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                        if ($(this).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
                            $(this).height(rowHight);
                            rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                            if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                                $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $(this.grid.fbDiv).height(this.grid.bDiv.clientHeight+1);
                    $(this.grid.fbDiv).css($(this.grid.bDiv).position());
                }
                if (this.grid.fhDiv !== undefined) {
                    $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.hDiv);
                    $('>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.fhDiv).each(function (i) {
                        var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                        $(this).height(rowHight);
                        rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                        if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                            $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                        }
                    });
                    $(this.grid.fhDiv).height(this.grid.hDiv.clientHeight);
                    $(this.grid.fhDiv).css($(this.grid.hDiv).position());
                }
            };
            var fixGboxHeight = function () {
                var gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight(),
                    pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();

                $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
                gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight();
                pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();
                $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
            };



            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                shrinkToFit:false,
                autowidth:true,
                height: 450,
                hoverrows: true,
                sortable: false,
                colNames:[' <br> <br> <br> <br>Year',
                          ' <br> <br> <br>Your<br>Age',
                          ' <br> <br> <br>Spouse<br>Age',
                          'Your Annual<br>Job<br>Income',
                          'Spouse Annual<br>Job<br>Income'
                colModel:[
                    {name:'year',index:'year', width:50, align:"center",sortable:false, sorttype:"int",classes:'spreadsheet_cell0', frozen:true},
                    {name:'age0',index:'age0', width:50, align:"center",sortable:false, sorttype:"int",frozen:true},
                    {name:'age1',index:'age1', width:50, align:"center",sortable:false, sorttype:"int",frozen:true},
                    {name:'salary0',index:'salary0',  width:100, align:"right",sortable:false,sorttype:"float",formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$"}},
                    {name:'salary1',index:'salary1',  width:100, align:"right",sortable:false,sorttype:"float",formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$"}}

                ],
                multiselect: false,
                rowNum:20,
                rowList:[10,20],
                altRows:false,
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id!=previous_row) {
                        previous_row=id;
                        }
                    },
                loadComplete: function () {

                                fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                        }
            });


        // ADD DATA TO THE GRID
            addData();

        $grid.jqGrid('gridResize', {
            minWidth: 450,
            stop: function () {
                fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                fixGboxHeight.call(this);
            }
        });
        $grid.bind("jqGridResizeStop", function () {
            resizeColumnHeader.call(this);
            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
            fixGboxHeight.call(this);
        });


        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            // apply the fix an all grids on the page on resizing of the page
            $("table.ui-jqgrid-btable").each(function () {
                fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                //fixGboxHeight.call(this);
            });
        });

        // after all that freeze the cols and fix the divs
        resizeColumnHeader.call($grid[0]);
        $grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
        $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
        fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call($grid[0]);
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid? If you would use the current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (4.13.5), then you can remove all the code, which fix bugs of old implementation of `setFrozenColumns`. You need just create the grid and call `setFrozenColumns`. By the way you should use `data` parameter of jqGrid *to create the grid filled with the data*. The usage of `addData`, where you probably call `addRowData` in the loop is the slowest way to fill the grid. See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: Wow Oleg thanks for responding!  YOu da man!  And yes AddData has a loop that adds the data to each cell... really slow.  I didn't code it though another guy did.  I will look into changing that.  Cool Cool.

Comment: Oleg did you change the syntax?  I switched to 4.13.5 without changing code I get:

Comment: Oleg did you change the syntax?  I switched to 4.13.5 without changing code I get:

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function

This occurs on the  $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                shrinkToFit:false,
                autowidth:true,
                height: 450,
                hoverrows: true,
                sortable: false,
etc. line of my code

Comment: The error jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function means typically that you didn't loaded jqGrid. Please verify that you loaded correct version of all jqGrid files. See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid_code) an example of the usage of free jqGrid. If you would have some problems, then you can post me the URL to the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you call jqGrid without the data?  Or is that required when you create the grid?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean under "call jqGrid". One can **create** the grid with or without data. The mostly effective is creating the grid *with data*, but one can first create the grid and then set/reset `data` and trigger "reloadGrid" finally. It reloads the grid *body* with new data. `var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");` get the reference to internal parameters of jqGrid, `p.data = newData;` - replace the data, `$grid.trigger("reloadGrid")` - reloads the data

Comment: I spent hours trying to do the frozen cols.  With jqgrid 5.2.0 the app works but frozen cols do not.  By ONLY trying to use the 4.13.5 version of free jqgrid it breaks the app as if it's not loading jquery anymore.  What version of jquery do we need to work with 4.13.5?   Also your free examples using a CDN for jqgrid that loads freely if I paste the url into a tab but if I use the same url from my server it gives 404 error.  Maybe they are blocking some referers I don't know.

Comment: Also I can't post my code bc it is way too complicated to strip out just the grid part.  I think the problem is the interaction between modules like jquery, bootstrap, and jqgrid... maybe incompatible versions???

Comment: The error 404 (file not found) means typically, that you made some typing error and use wrong URL. I can help you only if you provide the demo which reproduces the problem. You can start with the demo like https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4pkcbo7w/1/ and modify it to anyone, which you need.